# Difference between "..." and "pass" in class definition?

Tags: python

To my surprise, I learned a few months ago that

```py
class MyException(Exception):
    ...
```

is valid Python. It is surprisingly difficult to find references to the "..." syntax in the [Python Language Reference](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/index.html) so I have had a lot of difficulty understanding the exact difference between the above syntax and

```py
class MyException(Exception):
    pass
```

Is there a difference between the snippets above? Where is the first syntax `...` documented?

Comment: For starters, pass is a keyword and elipses is an actual object. Conventionally, `pass` is used when no code is meant to be present somewhere. And elipses (although rarely seen in my experience) are used for a WIP.

Comment: You can substitute `pass` for any other expression that simply doesn't produce any result, e.g. `None`. `pass` just explicitly does absolutely nothing and is only there as a syntactic placeholder.